# Outlook Mailcow wrong ssl certificate

Tags: email, ssl, lets-encrypt

Recently I set up a mail server (mailcow) with help of the following [tutorial](https://mailcow.github.io/mailcow-dockerized-docs/i_u_m_install/). I tried to login with Outlook, but Outlook says that the certificate can not be verified. Why is the value of the `issued to` field `mail.example.org` and not to `xxx.xxx.xx`?

[image: certificate]

**mailcow.conf:**

```
MAILCOW_HOSTNAME=xxx.xxx.xx

HTTP_PORT=8080
HTTP_BIND=0.0.0.0

HTTPS_PORT=8443
HTTPS_BIND=0.0.0.0

SMTP_PORT=25
SMTPS_PORT=465
SUBMISSION_PORT=587
IMAP_PORT=143
IMAPS_PORT=993
POP_PORT=110
POPS_PORT=995
SIEVE_PORT=4190
DOVEADM_PORT=127.0.0.1:19991
SQL_PORT=127.0.0.1:13306

ADDITIONAL_SAN=

# Skip running ACME (acme-mailcow, Let's Encrypt certs) - y/n

SKIP_LETS_ENCRYPT=n

# Skip IPv4 check in ACME container - y/n

SKIP_IP_CHECK=n

# Skip HTTP verification in ACME container - y/n

SKIP_HTTP_VERIFICATION=n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the configuration file I set `SKIP_LETS_ENCRYPT = y` and generated the ssl certificate with letsencrypt myself. Look [here](https://github.com/mailcow/mailcow-dockerized/issues/156).